# High school implicit differentiation question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A particle follows a path determined by the equation $x^2 + x = y^3 + 3y^2 + 2y + 2$. The x-coordinate
of the particle changes at a constant rate given by $dx/dt$ =$4$

Determine the rate at which the y-coordinates are changing when y = 0.

I've implicitly differentiated the above equation to get $dy/dx=(2x+1)/(3y^2+6y+2)$ but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Why can't you do this?

Comment: @JohnDouma not sure what to do next

Comment: What did you do first?

Comment: Use $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$.

Comment: If you solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ then you are not using implicit differentiation. The problem is asking for $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Comment: Cheers I get it now